# How to translate SonarQube Gradle plugin configuration from Groovy to Kotlin DSL

Tags: sonarqube-scan, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following configuration in my `build.gradle` that I would like to convert to Kotlin DSL:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        xml.destination(file("${jacoco.reportsDir}/my-tests/jacocoMyTestReport.xml"))
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", jacocoTestReport.reports.xml.destination
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt at converting the `sonarqube` block, but it fails with

> Unresolved reference: reports

```kotlin
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", tasks.named<JacocoReport>("jacocoTestReport").reports.xml.destination)
    }
}
```

What is wrong here? How can I access the `jacocoTestReport.reports.xml.destination` property using Kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

Please try something like that:

```
tasks {
    sonarqube {
        val path = jacocoTestReport.get().reports.xml.outputLocation.get()
        properties {
            property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", path)
        }
    }

    withType<org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarTask>().configureEach {
        dependsOn(test, jacocoTestReport)
    }
}
```

It works for me